# @JsonCreator 'Could not find creator property with name' even with ignoreUnknown = true

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Topic {

    private List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonCreator
    public Topic(@JsonProperty("success") boolean success,
                 @JsonProperty("response_comments") List<ResponseComment> responseComments,
                 @JsonProperty("response_users") List<ResponseUser> responseUsers) {

        if (success) {
            comments = Util.resolveComments(responseComments); 
            users = Util.resolveUsers(responseUsers); //some logic
        }

    }

}
```

When I try to deserialize JSON, it throws:

> Could not find creator property with name 'comments' (in class com.test.domain.mapper.Topic)

I don't want to fill `comments` from json, just in constructor from properties. However, if I write next params:

```
@JsonProperty("success") boolean success,
@JsonProperty("response_comments") List<ResponseComment> responseComments,
@JsonProperty("response_users") List<ResponseUser> responseUsers,
@JsonProperty("comments") Object a,
@JsonProperty("users") Object a
```

all works.

Comment: Creating an [mcve] helps us. Minimize the code, e.g. remove "response_comments" and "response_users". Provide the JSON as text. Then provide code that uses Jackson, ideally as a unit test. This will make me start caring. If I need to figure that out all myself, it's just too much effort.

Comment: I cannot reproduce, please show the content of your input JSON

Comment: I can only reproduce if I add getter and setter for the fields `comments` and `users`

Comment: Try to annotate `comments` and `users` with `@JsonIgnore`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

After hours of unit testing and copying of classes, I found a solution. I don't want to admit it, but the issue in the [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/)'s [@AllArgsConstructor](https://projectlombok.org/features/Constructor.html). I'm sorry that I didn't provided that I use Lombok at all.
Without `@AllArgsConstructor` in `Topic` all works as expected. However, it exists in other classes even with `@JsonCreator` and works. I'm sorry for your time.

Comment: Many thanks for updating your own answer. The pointer to Lombok's AllArgsConstructor being the issue saved me several hours of searching. I discovered the problem is with the annotation @java.beans.ConstructorProperties({ "value", "key" }) that Lombok adds to the  All Args Constructor when it generates it.

Comment: Same for me, I wasted some time but it could have been so much worse. I didn't expect Lombok to be able to cause such issues. Does someone know the root cause, out of curiosity?

Answer (score 13):

Using lomback's @AllArgsConstructor and jackson 2.8.7.
Upgrade jackson to 2.8.8 and problem resolved.

Comment: This solved the issue. Everything else was perfect. Only Jackson upgrade helped. I was using Jackson 2.8.7

Answer (score 4):

After working on this for a few hours and confirming the behavior experienced by @Feeco, I was able to resolve this issue by upgrading Lombok from v1.16.16 to v1.16.20.

Answer (score 2):

You should add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` to the creator method/Topic contructor.