# Jackson deserialisation error when upgrading spring-cloud-netflix from 1.3.0.M1 -> 1.3.0.RELEASE

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, spring-cloud-netflix

I am getting jackson deserialisation error when I upgraded spring cloud netflix from 1.3.0.M1 -> 1.3.0.RELEASE.

The Post request that I hit is

```
Received [POST /wms-mdm/catalog HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8093
Content-Type: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8093
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Safari/602.1.50
Referer: http://localhost:8093/wms-mdm/swagger-ui.html
Content-Length: 99
Accept-Language: en-us
```

With Data

```
{
"clientCatalogId": "7",
"shortDescription": "Dummy Catalog",
"longDescription": "Dummy Catalog"
}]
```

The error I am getting is:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Could not find creator property with name 'id' (in class com.gor.platform.mdm.core.pojo.Catalog)
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportMappingException(DeserializationContext.java:1234) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.addBeanProps(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:551) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.buildBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:226) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:141) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:403) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializerCache.java:191) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializationContext.java:421) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
>       at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.canDeserialize(ObjectMapper.java:2713) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.7.jar:2.8.7]
>       at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canRead(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:162) ~[spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:195) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:150) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:128) [spring-webmvc-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) [spring-web-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]

When I downgrade netflix cloud to old version things works fine. Anyone can help?

Comment: Are you using `lombok` ? Can you paste `Catalog` pojo class?

Comment: "@"Getter
"@"Setter
"@"Builder
"@"ToString
"@"EqualsAndHashCode
"@"AllArgsConstructor
"@"NoArgsConstructor
public class Catalog implements Serializable{

    private Long id;
    private String clientCatalogId;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String longDescription;
    "@"JsonIgnore
    private Date createdDate;
    "@"JsonIgnore
    private Date updatedDate;
}            Yes, I am using Lombok

Comment: Can you comment `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation alone and check?

Comment: Or add `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation to `Catalog` pojo class?

Comment: Tried both your suggestions. Still getting the same error.

Comment: am not seeing `id` field in your json. Why don't you ignore similar to `createdDate` and `updatedDate` fields ?

Comment: Id is auto generated in model and hence not passed in json. Also I tried jsonIgnore on Id. The same error shifts on the next attribute then.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40546508/jsoncreator-could-not-find-creator-property-with-name-even-with-ignoreunknown might help you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Adding explicit dependency for jackson-databind 2.8.8 solved the issue. Looks like some problem with 2.8.7